# Why do I not see any results from my For-loop?

Tags: procedural-programming

I am sure I am missing something trivial :-( Still any help is welcome.

```
ec1[c1_, c2_] := 1/c1
ec2[c1_, c2_] := 1/c2
Bcom[b_, c1_, c2_] := ec1[c1, c2] - (ec1[c1, c2] - ec2[c1, c2])

 X = {}
 For[a = 10, a < 100, a += 10,
   For[i = 1, i < 100, i += 5,
     For[j = i + 1, j <= 50, j += 4,
       AppendTo[X, {Bcom[a, i, j]}]]]]
```

Comment: It is. Check `X`. _Afterwards_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ec1[c1_, c2_] := 1/c1
ec2[c1_, c2_] := 1/c2
Bcom[b_, c1_, c2_] := ec1[c1, c2] - (ec1[c1, c2] - ec2[c1, c2])

X = {};
For[a = 10, a < 100, a += 10,
  For[i = 1, i < 100, i += 5,
   For[j = i + 1, j <= 50, j += 4,
    AppendTo[X, {Bcom[a, i, j]}]
    ]]];
X
```

Or more idiomatic in Mathematica and taking 60% of the time

```
X2=Flatten[Table[
  {Bcom[a, i, j]}
  , {a, 10, 100 - 10, 10}
  , {i, 1, 100 - 5, 5}
  , {j, i + 1, 50, 4}
  ], 2];
```

Check the result is the same

```
X===X2
(* True *)
```

Comment: Just too tired... Thank you